# Folder permission?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

This is the code for function that I use for setting folder permission:

```
 Public Sub AddFileSecurity(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal power As String)

        Dim dirinfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(filePath)

        Dim dirsecurity As DirectorySecurity = dirinfo.GetAccessControl()

        Select Case power

            Case "FullControl"

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

            Case "ReadOnly"

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow))

            Case "Write"

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

            Case "Modify"

                dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow))

        End Select

        dirinfo.SetAccessControl(dirsecurity)

    End Sub



Public Sub RemoveFileSecurity(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal power As String)

Dim dirinfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(filePath)

Dim dirsecurity As DirectorySecurity = dirinfo.GetAccessControl()

Select Case power

    Case "FullControl"

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Deny))

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Deny))

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Deny))

    Case "ReadOnly"

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Deny))

    Case "Write"

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Deny))

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Deny))

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Deny))

    Case "Modify"

        dirsecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny))

End Select

dirinfo.SetAccessControl(dirsecurity)

End Sub
```

Now when i lock folder with   AddFileSecurity("D:\Protect", "UserUser", "FullControl"), after that i can't unlock folder!

How I can unlock this folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `power` parameter should be an enum instead of a string.

Comment: But when I call function RemoveFileSecurity("D:\Protect", "UserUser", "FullControl") I can access to D:\Protect, and that is what I wont but now when i need to return access on this folder to UserUser i don't know how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AddFileSecurity` is correctly named but your `RemoveFileSecurity` doesn't actually remove anything, instead it ***denies*** access. In `AddFileSecurity` you should add a call to remove any `Deny` entries for that user, probably `RemoveAccessRuleAll`.